# Setting point colors based on value in D3 v3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just created a US map using example from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340. I also plotted some values based on long and lat. At the moment, all I can do is add a single color value to those points. How can I create a range of colors so that the color of those points changes based on the values.

Here's how I'm adding the points on the map:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .range(["#ffebee, #ffcdd2, #ef9a9a, #e57373, #ef5350, #f44336, #e53935, #d32f2f, #c62828, #b71c1c, #ff8a80, #ff5252, #ff1744, #d50000"]);

g.selectAll("circle")
 .data($ctrl.marks).enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("class", "point")
 .style("fill", function (d) { console.log(d.average); return colorScale(d.average) })   //added this to try it. 
 .attr("r", 3)
 .attr("transform", function (d) {
       return "translate(" + projection([d.lng, d.lat]) + ")";
     })
```

There are 50 points that I'm showing on the map. Do I also need 50 color range?

Comment: This needs more information, or a JSFiddle example of it in action. The code includes colorScale - is that not working? Does `console.log(d.average)` correctly show points having an average property?  Perhaps [browse the documentation for the scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#linear-scales) and try setting a proper `domain`, based on the values contained in `average`?

Comment: I just figured out how to do that. I had to use d3.scale.linear().domain().range() and give data value minimum and maximum array for domain, and minimum and maximum color code array. Then it's only a matter of using it in the code. I figured this out using d3. examples on choropleth maps.